# Could't run java headless selenium

Tags: java, selenium, amazon-web-services, firefox

I tried to run selenium script in java. But everytime i tried to create firefox driver i'm getting this error

```
[WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 

(process:32000): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

(firefox:32000): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Error: no display specified
```

Some background about my problem.

1. I tried to running selenium with ubuntu 14.0.4 on aws ec2
2. I already tried to install xvfb so the firefox can run in headless mode and run the xvfb with some references (https://medium.com/@griggheo/running-selenium-webdriver-tests-using-firefox-headless-mode-on-ubuntu-d32500bb6af2#.u0hrlct41, https://gist.github.com/curtismcmullan/7be1a8c1c841a9d8db2c)
3. I could run selenium python script without any problem
4. I'm using this selenium sbt in my java selenium script **"org.seleniumhq.selenium" % "selenium-java" % "2.53.1",**

can anyone help me to run the headless selenium using java ?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these steps if you want to run Selenium java test suites in headless mode. You can run against chrome browser in headless mode. Good luck!

```
1) /usr/bin/Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &

2) export DISPLAY=:1

4) make all version same 2.53.1 for selenium

5) add profile for chrome 

6) Add chrome driver (Linux version) in test resorurces folder.
```

Answer (score 0):

somehow i did setup java selenium headless.

i tried using fresh ubuntu 14.0.4 machine and follow this link

http://tobyho.com/2015/01/09/headless-browser-testing-xvfb/

some important thing that you must take a notes!

1. make sure your selenium version is compatible with your firefox version (in my case i'm using selenium **2.53.1** and firefox **47.0.1**)
2. everytime i'm ssh my server i must rerun the xvfb and set the local variable.